# На одной странице @media screen работает на другой нет. Почему так?

Tags: php

На этой работает `http://пождверь.рф/`
На этой нет `http://пождверь.рф/otpravit_zayavku/`

При переходе через консоль в режим мобилы на главной странице `@media screen` работает, при переходе на страницу `http://пождверь.рф/otpravit_zayavku/` они не работают.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/178988

Comment: у меня в фф в режиме адаптивного дизайна для тлф в целом обе ссылки показываются одинаково, на первом кнопка "Меню" два раза дублируется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убедись в наличии

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag