# Google chrome андроид css table td

Tags: css

Есть таблица с двумя колонками, желаемый результат такой на мобильных устройствах показать в одну колонку с помощи css.

Написал такой css код

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    #unpiwep td {
        display:block;
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
                box-sizing:border-box;
        clear:both;
        width: 100%;

    }
}
```

Однако если смотреть через инспектора браузера, то все работает идеально, одна колонка, но захожу со сматфона через браузер google chrome эти css стили уже не работают и также отображаются в две колонки. Как можно победить подобное?

Сама таблица такая

```
<table id="unpiwep">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="photo"></td>
            <td class="photo"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="photo"></td>
            <td class="photo"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: а что будет если не `width:100%;` а `width:100vw;` задать?

Comment: Да пробовал уже vw, всё также.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/733572/178988 - оно?

Comment: А вообще, не издевайся над таблицей.

Answer (score 1):

Причин «Почему не работает код на смартфоне может быть несколько:

1) Старый кэш CSS в браузере. В этом случае почисти браузер.
2) Если у тебя несколько медиа-запросов, то свойства одних могут перебивать свойства других. Или неправильный порядок Запросов.
В этом случае, попробуй как в коде ниже добавить после каждого свойства нужного: «!important». Пример:

```
  #unpiwep td {
    display: block !important;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
    clear: both !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    text-align: center !important;
  }
```

3) Несколько файлов css, перебивающее свойства друг другу, аналогично как и в «2».

4) Другая причина. Которой в теории нет места.

В остальном код работает:

```css
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  #unpiwep td {
    display: block !important;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
    clear: both !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    text-align: center !important;
  }
  #unpiwep {
    background-color: #3F51B5;
    color: yellow;
  }
  #unpiwep,
  #unpiwep tbody,
  #unpiwep tr,
  #unpiwep td {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="unpiwep">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="photo">тест 1</td>
      <td class="photo">тест 2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="photo">тест 3</td>
      <td class="photo">тест 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```